# IPFS Desktop same base URL

Tags: solidity, nft, ipfs

I am trying to same URL Base for all my uploads on IPFS but if I upload a directory or one file at a time, each of them has a different base, which is then hard to use for a smart contract where I would just change ID and use the same base URL.

How to do it with IPFS I saw projects having URLS like
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmeSjSinHpPnmXmspMjwiXyN6zS4E9zccariGR3jxcaWtq/9151

where they just change ID at the end, how?

Answer (score 1):

Seems what I need is this https://dweb-primer.ipfs.io/files-on-ipfs/wrap-directories-around-content to wrap directory around files, this gives base URL.